# Как заменить строку в Collection<String> name?

Tags: java, строки, list, коллекции, arraylist

```
public void resetWordsByLength(Collection<String> e, int n) {
    Iterator<String> iterator = e.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if (iterator.next().length() == n) {
            iterator.next().replaceAll(iterator.next(), "*");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: что значит заменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Строки в Java неизменямые, и `String::replaceAll` просто создаст новую строку, которая никоим образом не сохранится в текущей коллекции.
2. В общем случае, такая замена может быть невозможна (сама коллекция неизменяема) или бессмысленна -- например, для Set несколько *разных* строк одинаковой длины `n` будут заменены *одной* строкой "*".

Поэтому следует рассмотреть замену элементов отдельно в списке `List` и во множестве `Set`.

Если коллекция представляет собой список `List<String>`, можно использовать либо итерацию по индексу и обычный метод [`List::set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-), или же обёртку в виде метода [`List::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-):

```java
public void resetWordsByLengthWithSet(List<String> e, int n) {
    for (int i = 0, sz = e.size(); i < sz; i++) {
        String s = e.get(i);
        if (s.length() == n) {
            // заменить слово одной звездочкой
            e.set(i, s.replaceAll(s, "*"));

            // или заменить n звездочками, String::repeat в Java 11+
            // e.set(i, "*".repeat(n));
        }
    }
}
```

Аналогично, можно проитерировать список при помощи `ListIterator`, у которого также есть операция [`ListIterator::set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set-E-), позволяющая заменить текущий элемент.

```java
public void resetWordsByLengthWithSet(List<String> e, int n) {
    ListIterator<String> li = e.listIterator();
    while (li.hasNext()) {
        String s = li.next();
        if (s.length() == n) {
            li.set("*");
        }
    }
}
// кратчайший способ замены при помощи тернарного оператора
public void resetWordsByLengthWithReplaceAll(List<String> e, int n) {
    e.replaceAll(s -> s.length() == n ? "*" : s);
}
```

---

Для замены в *модифицируемом* множестве `Set` можно воспользоваться методом `Collection::removeIf`, и в зависимости от его результата следует добавить *единственную* строку `"*"`:

```java
public void resetWordsByLengthWithRemoveIf(Set<String> e, int n) {
    if (e.removeIf(s -> s.length() == n)) {
        e.add("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо громадное